# How can we create cross region RDS read replica using AWS cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, read-replication

I have easily found a way to create RDS read replica in same region using AWS cloud formation, but:
1. Can we create the same in different region using CF template?
2. Also can we promote it to primary using CF template?

Comment: This does not seem to be the case with Aurora Engine. I believe we can create a read replica through the AWS CLI, Management Console for Aurora, but I don't see support for it in CF templates, could someone correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 6):

1) Yes, you can create a RDS read replica in different region using CloudFormation. Create a CloudFormation template in target region (where you want to create the read-replica) and give the ***source database instance arn*** (which is in source region) as input for `SourceDBInstanceIdentifier`.

```
Resources:
  # Create Data DB
  myReplciaDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: "read-replica"
      PubliclyAccessible: false
      SourceDBInstanceIdentifier: "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:XXXXXX:db:source-database"
      StorageType: gp2
```

Check this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-sourcedbinstanceidentifier) for more info.

2) Currently, I dont think it is possible to promote a read replica using cloudformation. But you can achieve this using a lambda function.

- Create a lambda function in the target region, which uses the `promote-read-replica` api in the sdk of your choice.
- Create a sns topic in the source region,and add it as a trigger for the lambda function. *Dont forget to add invoke permission for SNS to the Lambda using the SNSTopicArn*.
- In source RDS console, Go to Event Subscription and select the ***sns topic arn*** you created above as the target arn to receive events. Under event categories, select `deletion, failure` for you source database.

Comment: for 1) do you need to create a DBCluster first?